# javascript, IE 7-9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In IE 7-9: When I click in input text box - placeholder removed and place it set the text, but cursor go to start of text, but I want that the cursor was at the end of text. How to change cursor position or set in the end of text, that it work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean however, if I'm thinking correctly this may be what you want to do:

```
<input id="textBoxId" type="text" value="This is my Value" size="50" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" />
```

Let me know if this helps or please expand your question  / include some code